# Moderator ability to make a post invisible

Tags: feature-request, edits, moderator-tools

The first question in the moderator questionaire (for reference below) is:

> Q1: An asker repeatedly flags their own question and says that they need to delete it or they'll be fired, because they mistakenly posted proprietary code. There are several good answers on that question. What do you do?

This made me wonder: Do moderators have the ability to make a question **temporarily invisible**? This would give the original poster and the moderator time to handle/edit the question in whatever way is appropriate without actually *deleting* the post.

They may already have this ability; I wouldn't know. But if they don't, I think it would be a good one to have not just for this situation but for others as well. Likely, this feature should include an automatic *reappear* timeout, after, perhaps, an hour, it reappears at the top of the active queue - to make it different from an actual deletion.

Comment: No but they can disassociate a question from its author's account which is close enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That doesn't, in any way, make the content invisible.

Comment: @Servy it's "giving the original poster and the moderator time to handle/edit the question in whatever way is appropriate" while the original poster identity is hidden, which I think is what the OP here is after.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 1) It's not an easily reversible action when you disassociate the account form the post 2) It doesn't prevent the community from interacting with the post while it is discussed 3) It doesn't prevent the sensitive information from being stolen, which is of course what the whole thing is about.  Identifying the author is not the issue here, it's having someone steal the proprietary information.  Not getting caught for leaking sensitive information still results in the person leaking sensitive information, so it's not really solving the problem in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, they can delete it.  This makes the post visible only to the author, other moderators, and other 10k+ users.

Virtually all deletions are soft deletes, meaning all of that information is still there in the database, it's just not exposed publicly.  Moderators aren't even *capable* of hard deleting content (which is actually truly making it "gone" and unrecoverable, only devs can do that).

Having said that, barring particularly exceptional situations (which, actually, I could see a mod arguing that this is a suitable exceptional situation), mods are generally not encouraged to delete first and then sort it out later.  They should generally be quite confident that a post really does deserve deletion, and be prepared to justify that decision if asked about it, *before* they delete something.

Comment: Million-dollar idea: rename "delete" to "hide"

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Not enough moneys in the world for that.

Comment: I should say that we do delete first and undelete later when login credentials and other sensitive information have been posted. That's the approach that the community team recommends while waiting for them to burn the old revisions that had this information.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That's a terrible idea D: