# Inconsistency, Craziness in a particular question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, revisions-list

I was on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24418359/462627):

[image]

It looks like a haunted page, with no revisions giving the right information, when you click on any revision, looks like the revision and the contents do not match.

[image]

And also the next crazy thing I saw is, when I expand the votes:

[image]

All the votes were `0 / 0`, which cannot be possible. Even if it is caching, I don't think these are cached for an year?

Can [Sklivvz ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz) or someone explain me what's happening on here? If this was intended, why isn't it consistent? [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: I observed this vote count behavior several times with deleted users. I guess the vote count is not recomputed when the user that voted gets deleted. Looks like you can trigger recalculation when you show the expanded votes, thus it shows the correct count now..

Comment: @Floern the vote count issue is due to invalidated votes, it happens when sock puppet accounts are used, then merged, then it actually means the user voted on his own posts - so it's invalidated, not deleted. (i.e. the votes are still there in the database, just have no effect)

Comment: They are hiding precious drama from us!  We must haves it!

Comment: @Won't Exactly, at least 20k+ users...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stack Exchange employees have, and always had, the power to make edits without leaving a trace in the revisions.

This is useful for cases like posting private information by mistake  (e.g.passwords) or, as in this case, some major trolling with extreme bad language. So the SE employee who appears as the editor made such a permanent edit without leaving a trace in the revisions.

Recently (February 2016) moderators also [got this same power](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision/274274#274274), though not single-handedly.

Comment: Ha ha ha... That's really bad... :P

Comment: Lemme wait until the person replies...

Comment: @Praveen what person? Who?

Comment: [Sklivvz ♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz)

Comment: What makes you think he will reply? There are thousands of bug reports here, only few get official reply. I still wait for replies to direct comments I left years ago. Besides, what I posted is not a guess. That's how things work, you won't likely get a better response anyway

Comment: I definitely respect and appreciate your time, and that's why I have voted you up as well. Just for my peace of mind and gut feeling, I might get a reply. Else, yours will be the future accepted answer. `:)`

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to let you know that most chances are that you won't get such a reply.

Comment: I understand... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar - This is the correct answer. Those answers were left as a part of a trolling attack on a specific moderator, and SE employees redacted their content because of the nature of what was posted. Like is stated, nothing more to see here.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks buddy, accepted it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar To clarify, the votes changed when you expanded them because the score is cached. There is a script that automatically fixes them and runs at midnight UTC every night, but it does not fix deleted posts because they're, well, deleted. Attempting to expand the votes recalculated and fixed the score manually.

Comment: Sure and thanks @animuson.